# How to handle invalid String format?

Tags: swift, string, string-formatting

Let's say I have this String format

```
String(format: "Text %i %i %i", 0, 1)
```

It will interrupt execution because the format is invalid. 
But is there a way to catch an exception to handle this error?

I don't see exception in documentation for the String initWithFormat.

Thanks

Comment: I should think it fails to compile due to too few arguments

Comment: Actually I'm loading the string format from a remote server. So string isn't known at compilation time. That's why I want to check if it fails at runtime.

Comment: Using anything but a string *literal* (i.e. a compile-time constant) as format string is a bad idea.  If the arguments do not match the format specifiers (in count or type) then you have undefined behaviour. Everything can happen, from wrong output to crash or a possible security exploit. And no, you cannot catch that.

Comment: This way I will use a custom string like [MY_VAR] and I will do a string replace on this.